# Perl - WWW::Mechanize::Firefox - Open link in new tab

Tags: perl, www-mechanize-firefox

Using the `$mech->find_all_links_dom` method I get an array of links on a page. For each `$link` in the array I want to open it in a new tab. I can't figure out how to do this, and advice would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way to work:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use WWW::Mechanize::Firefox;

my @array = <DATA>;

foreach (@array)
{
    my $mech = WWW::Mechanize::Firefox->new(    
                        activate => 1,  # bring the tab to the foreground
                        autoclose => 0  # to prevent autoclosing of the Tab
                        ); 
    $mech->get($_);
}

__DATA__
www.google.com
www.yahoo.com
```

AFAIK, `WWW::Mechanize::Firefox` opens the page in the same tab for a given object (`$mech`). So, I run a `foreach loop` and create a new object for each link. This may not be the BEST approach but this works.

Comment: I am pretty sure it is the only way. Every `WWW:Mechanize::Firefox` object has one tab associated with it. So if you want more tabs open at the same time, you need more objects.